# Keras Flatten layer in Functional API?

Tags: keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + (52,)))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
print(model.summary())
```

I want to change this keras code in sequential version to same code with functional version like the following.

```
input = Input(shape=(1,) + (52,))
i = Flatten()(input)
h = Dense(100, activation='relu')(i)
o = Dense(2, activation='linear')(h)
model = Model(inputs=i, outputs=o)
model.summary()
```

But it got error

```
  File "C:\Users\SDS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 237, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "C:\Users\SDS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1430, in _map_graph_network
    str(layers_with_complete_input))
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 1, 52), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Answer (score 14):

Your model definition is incorrect, the inputs parameter of Model should go to your Input layer, like this:

```
input = Input(shape=(1,) + (52,))
i = Flatten()(input)
h = Dense(100, activation='relu')(i)
o = Dense(2, activation='linear')(h)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=o)
```

I believe you cannot put any tensor other than the Input layer as input to a model.

Answer (score 0):

The input for model should be input layer(first layer without any dense layer).
So it should be like :

**model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=o)**